# Stop Sounds When Leaving Frame! FLASH AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I want the background sounds to stop when the user clicks on the next frame, how would this work out?

The code i'm using is:

```
   var req4:URLRequest = new URLRequest("TickTock.mp3");
   var TickTock: Sound = new Sound();
   TickTock.load(req4);

   TickTock.play(0);
```

When i add `ticktock.stop();`  this will come up:
Call to a possibly undefined method stop through a reference with static type flash.media:Sound.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call `.stop();` in the clickListener for the button. and not call it in the next frame itself as it will be out of scope.
 show the code for your button.

Also to use `.stop();` you will have to attache it to a SoundChannel

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("TickTock.mp3"));
myChannel = mySound.play();
```

then call

```
myChannel.stop();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked amazingly well with my project. Thank you again. :)